resolve two dbcontexts in one solution in .net core with repository pattern
I have two DbContext types:
private static readonly AutomationContext _aContext;
private static readonly RajaDb2Context _bContext;

And I also have two repositories:
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T? GetById(object id);
    T? GetOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Add(T entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Update(T entity);
    void UpdateRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
}

public interface IRepository2<T>
{
    T? GetById(object id);
    T? GetOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Add(T entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Update(T entity);
    void UpdateRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
}

I need to pass AutomationContext to IRepository and pass Raja2Db to IRepository2.
I added a resolver to my code like this:
public static class DependencyResolver<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly AutomationContext _aContext;
    private static readonly RajaDb2Context _bContext;

    public static IRepository<T> ResolveAutomation
    {
        get
        {
            return new Repository<T>(_aContext);
        }
    }

    public static IRepository2<T> Raja2
    {
        get
        {
            return new RajaDb2Repository<T>(_bContext);
        }
    }
}

But when I want to add the resolver to my Ioc:
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), DependencyResolver<>.ResolveAutomation);
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository2<>), DependencyResolver<>.Raja2);

I get this error:

Error CS0305
Using the generic type 'DependencyResolver' requires 1 type arguments

My repository implementation:
  public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
  {
      private readonly DbContext _context;

      public Repository(DbContext context)
      {
          _context = context;
      }

      public T? GetById(object id)
      {
          return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
      }

      public T? GetOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
      {
          return _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
      }

      public IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
      {
          return _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
      }

      public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
      {
          return _context.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
      }

      public void Add(T entity)
      {
          _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
          _context.SaveChanges();
      }

      public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
      {
          _context.Set<T>().AddRange(entities);
          _context.SaveChanges();
      }

      public void Remove(T entity)
      {
          _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
          _context.SaveChanges();
      }

      public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
      {
          _context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entities);
          _context.SaveChanges();
      }

      public void Update(T entity)
      {
          _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
          _context.SaveChanges();
      }

      public void UpdateRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
      {
          _context.Set<T>().UpdateRange(entities);
          _context.SaveChanges();
      }
  }


You could use Keyed services instead of having 2 interfaces. But even if you choose to differentiate the services by interface, then at least re-use the same interface by deriving two interfaces from it:
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T? GetById(object id);
    T? GetOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Add(T entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Update(T entity);
    void UpdateRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
}

public interface IRepository1<T> : IRepository<T>
{
}

public interface IRepository2<T> : IRepository<T>
{
}

Then you can do the same with the implementations
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly DbContext _context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // TODO: implement interface
}

public class AutomationRepository<T> : Repository<T>, IRepository1<T>
{
    public AutomationRepository()
        : base(new AutomationContect())
    {
    }
}

public class RajaDb2Repository<T> : Repository<T>, IRepository2<T>
{
    public RajaDb2Repository()
        : base(new RajaDb2Contect())
    {
    }
}

Now you can register
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository1<>), typeof(AutomationRepository<>));
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository2<>), typeof(RajaDb2Repository<>));

